# Node and npm with FTP

Tags: node.js, npm, ftp, vite

I have an issue with my application(a chatbot made with Vite/Node.js). When I run the command: npm run dev in the terminal inside vscode, I can open the localhost and use the application. But when I try to upload the files to my ftp server, and then open the website to run the applicaton, it does not work. I have looked for hours, and found out that the reason for this issue, is that my ftp server, does not have node.js and npm installed. So I guess my question is. How do I install node.js and npm on my ftp server, so that I am able to run this "npm run dev" command on the server? Btw, I am a beginner developer, with under 1 year of experience.

Comment: FTP server is used to send and receive files. The machine that you send the file to, has to run the node command the same as you do on your local pc. But I feel like this is an XY problem. Do you have a node.js server or just a website that uses vite?

Comment: I have a domain-name with a webhotel, that I can upload files to using FTP. I do not know what kind of server it is. I have previously uploaded html, css and javascript to it with success.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm run build` to get the static files out of vite?

Comment: Hi! Can you send me an email, and we can talk more there? Veggern_94@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty board question. But as you have discovered you can not use node on websites that are statically hosted. You can only use javascript, CSS, and HTML.

If you want to have a server, node running with a framework like express, then you need to host the server. But that is a giant topic, you could google it; there are many ways to host a back end service that is running node. (for instance an EC2 container on AWS)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So there is no way for me to just install node and npm inside my ftp server to get this to work ?

Comment: That is correct. (it comes down to where it's being hosted, that host probably also sells some hosting plan that offers running node)

Comment: Ahh okei. Thank you for clearing it up! I hope my question will help other noobies who experience this

Comment: @vigardAnson if your entire site is a vite project, you can just build it and send the final files

Comment: Hi, I do not know if the entire project is Vite. I have used a guide to build it. And installed both, node, npm, vite and express.